# Listing items by category with pagination

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pagination

I have a php page with pagination concept to list items from DB and list the items with alphabets also. Like if clicking "a", display name which are starting with letter "a" with a limit of 10, and the remaining should come in next page. if the alphabet is not selected, then all items are display with pagination. I have tried, but the pagination and category list are working separately.

```
$alpha='';
    if(isset($_REQUEST['alphabet_let']))
    {
    $alpha=$_REQUEST['alphabet_let'];
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['flag']))
    {
    $flag = $_REQUEST['flag'];  
    }
?>


        <div class='cc'  listTyp="<?php echo $_POST['listTyp'];?>"  catId="<?php echo $_POST['catId'];?>" alpha=<?php echo $alpha;?>>
        <?php $objOrg= new mysql_profile();
    $tbl_name="profile_organization";   

    $adjacents = 3;

    if($_POST['listTyp']=="mul")
    {   
        $arrOrg= $objOrg->select_admin_profileorgs(0,0,'','',$_POST['catId']);
        if($alpha!="")
        {
        $arrOrg= $objOrg->select_admin_profileorgs(0,0,$alpha,'',$_POST['catId']);
        }
    }
    else
    {

        $arrOrg= $objOrg->select_admin_profileorgs(0,$_POST['catId'],'','','');
        if($alpha!="")
        {
        $arrOrg= $objOrg->select_admin_profileorgs(0,$_POST['catId'],$alpha,'','');
        }if($flag !=''){
        $arrOrg= $objOrg->select_admin_profileorgs(0,$_POST['catId'],'','','','','','','','',$flag);
        }
    }
    $total_pages= count($arrOrg);

    if($alpha!=""){
        $gsts=$_REQUEST['alphabet_let']; 
        $targetpage = "catID.php?alphabet_let=$gsts";
    }else{
    $targetpage = "catID.php"; 
    }

    //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit =10;                                 //how many items to show per page
    $page = 1;  

    if(isset($_REQUEST['page']))
    {
        $page = $_REQUEST['page'];  
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['page']) && isset($_REQUEST['alphabet_let']))
    {
         $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
        echo $let = $_REQUEST['alphabet_let'];          
    }
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1


    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a class='prepage' href=\"$targetpage&page=$prev\">&#171; </a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">&#171; </span>";    

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a class='pagee' href=\"$targetpage&page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a class='pagee' href=\"$targetpage&page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a class='pagee' href=\"$targetpage&page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a class='pagee' href=\"$targetpage&page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";     
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a class='pagee' href=\"$targetpage&page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a class='pagee' href=\"$targetpage&page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a class='pagee' href=\"$targetpage&page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a class='pagee' href=\"$targetpage&page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a class='pagee' href=\"$targetpage&page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";     
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a class='pagee' href=\"$targetpage&page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a class='pagee' href=\"$targetpage&page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a class='pagee' href=\"$targetpage&page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
                }
            }
        }


        //next button

        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a class='nxtpage' href=\"$targetpage&page=$next\"> &#187;</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">&#187;</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }
?>      
            <?php
    $objOrg= new mysql_profile();
    $objLocn = new mysql_ix_location();
    $arrOrg = array();
    if($_POST['listTyp']=="mul")
    {   
        $arrOrg= $objOrg->select_admin_ix_profileorgs(0,0,'',$strlimit,$_POST['catId'],'',0,'order');
        if($alpha!="")
        {
        $arrOrg= $objOrg->select_admin_ix_profileorgs(0,0,$alpha,$strlimit,$_POST['catId'],'',0,'order');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $arrOrg= $objOrg->select_admin_ix_profileorgs(0,$_POST['catId'],'',$strlimit,'','',0,'order');
        if($alpha!="")
        {
        $arrOrg= $objOrg->select_admin_ix_profileorgs(0,$_POST['catId'],$alpha,$strlimit,'','',0,'order');
        }if($flag !=''){
        $arrOrg= $objOrg->select_admin_ix_profileorgs(0,$_POST['catId'],'',$strlimit,'','',0,'order','','',$flag);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and ... ? have you tried anything ?

Comment: yes, i use a script with ajax

Comment: When you asking something here, you better post your code if you want to get your answer.

Comment: i edited the question, please check this

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql query would be like

```
SELECT * FROM  `your_table` WHERE  `column_name` LIKE  '$your_query%' LIMIT 0 , 10
```

where 0 would be your page number -1.

Comment: i use it, but my problem is in php script, that is editing in my question